# QuestDB support for the Julia programming language

Tags: julia, questdb

Julia is a high performance programming language that can handle large amounts of data fast, and it seems to be gaining momentum (https://www.hpcwire.com/2021/01/13/julia-update-adoption-keeps-climbing-is-it-a-python-challenger/).

I have not seen any mentions of the language on QuestDB's documentation/guides. Are there any plans to provide support for Julia?. Are there any good resources out there on how to get started with QuestDB through Julia?.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any official documentation, however Dean Markwick shows how to use QuestDB with Julia in his blog post series [here](https://dm13450.github.io/2021/08/05/questdb-part-1.html) and [here](https://dm13450.github.io/2021/08/12/questdb-part2.html)

Comment: Thank you @Astad !! these look like excellent articles, these are the titles:
- Using QuestDB to Build a Crypto Trade Database in Julia
- QuestDB Part 2 - High Frequency Finance (again!)